# What is the best way to visually present a sitemap?

Tags: website-design, design-patterns, info-visualisation, sitemap

Do you know which are the common patterns for a graphical representation of a sitemap?

Comment: Do you want to present a sitemap for your clients or on a web site a a navigation tool?

Answer (score 10):

Hagan Rivers proposed a very useful model of representing a site's navigation during her presentation [Escaping Navigation Hell, you should look into it](http://www.uie.com/brainsparks/2010/06/11/spoolcast-hagan-rivers-escaping-navigation-hell-live/). She says it's better to use an application map since the navigation system can be viewed as an application on itself that has the objective of taking you to the screen you need.

It's so much clearer than a regular sitemap, and it looks a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

**Flowcharts** are the most common tool for visually representing site structure, as far as I know.

Here are a couple of examples:

---

[image: flowchart 1]

---

[image: flowchart image 2]

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic but there is no 'flow' in those examples ! They are more like an organogram because they show 'organisation' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizational_chart

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample of mobile phone menu navigation. This is just an idea.

[image]

to Clara Gaggero for [more details](http://www.claragaggero.com/?p=135)

Answer (score -2):

You'd try to represent it like a flow-chart with links and interactions between pages.